# GWT-Java- Popup without loosing focus?

Tags: java, validation, gwt, popup

I have just begun looking into this issue, but this has always been a great resource for me.

I need to create a popup (containing error validation) that will stay 'up' while the user enters data correcting the issues identified in the popup.

When they are complete they would close the popup and try saving again.

Is this possible? Any ideas/ advice? Any guidance for completing this would be greatly appreciated.

**I am using GWT 2.4

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
PopupPanel errorValidatorPopUp = new PopupPanel();
errorValidatorPopUp.center();// to show the popup at centre of page or 
                                else you can setPosition
errorValidatorPopUp.setGlassEnabled(true);//for Modal" effect blocking background

/** your Logic for error validator **/
    Create a Panel with error validator widgets on it 
    Once done add to the errorValidatorPopup

    eg : all your widgets on an errorPanel,

errorValidatorPopup.add(errorPanel);

errorValidatorPopup.show(); //to show popup
```

You can have a button on the errorPanel to call errorValidatorPopup.hide() once your validation is done.

`PopupPanel` documentation for reference is [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PopupPanel.html)

Comment: So your sure this will allow me to edit widgets on the page while the popup is open at the same time? I guess my question is more how to handle the focus... eclipse actually functions the way I need. If you select some code, control-F, a user can switch focus between the find popup and the code.

Comment: I thought you want to do error validation on the popup.. This will be modal what you want is a non modal pop-up.